# Diffussion coefficient of blood

Tags: microbiology

What it the diffusion coefficient of blood in, e.g. water? 
It is needed for microchannel length calculations

I have found a bit different nubmers: 0.94 and 1.66 microns^2/ms, but not sure

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please add references to your question (i.e. where you obtained those numbers). Also, please clarify whether you are asking about human blood. If so, can you specify what population(s) of humans this blood is from. There wont be a single number since blood viscosity (which will affect diffusion) can vary significantly both within and between populations — e.g. people living at high altitudes typically show increased blood viscosity.  You may find this article interesting: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4162413/